# Django M2M save and add relationship for each relative

Tags: python, django, m2m

i have one silly problem with Django M2M saving.
I don't use Django Admin (use my own custom templates)

So, I have simple relationship:

```
# models
class News(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=256)

class Webmaster(AbstractUser):
    ...
    news = models.ManyToManyField(News)
```

I need after saving every news mark it as new to every webmaster. So i figure out something like this:

```
# models
class News(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=256)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.id:
            news = News.objects.all()[0]
            self.webmasters.add(news)
        super(News, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

But i try like 6-7 different ways, and my code still don't work, can you help? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use post_save () signal, add this code in models.py

```
def Webmaster_add(sender, instance, **kwargs):
     #you can put here some condition stuff
     w = Webmasters.objects.all()
     for obj in w:
         obj.news.add(instance)

# register the signal
post_save.connect(webmaster_add, sender=News)
```

Comment: If he wants to do it for every webmaster he would have to query all the webmasters inside the signal and add the instance.

Comment: thanks! Will try this.. I really want to add news to every webmaster.

Comment: `type object 'Webmaster' has no attribute 'add'`

Comment: I have updated my code, please retry it and let me know

Comment: I have no idea why, but it took so much time to load (5+ minutes), and it's still don't finished. And u have no errors.  Anyway, thank you for your time.

Comment: Because we used 
w = Webmasters.objects.all()
     for obj in w:
         obj.news.add(instance)
for loop

Comment: It is weird,  check your other code. If it inserts data in manytomany  table field, then answer is perfect,